# Ajax Post Error Text Field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I can not figure out how to get the text from my text field `login_ConfigPostken` 
to be sent through my POST ajax request. For this POST I need to send over the key_id, which is in the format of `{"xtalk.user": "test"}`. The format of the message to be typed into my text field in `{"<name of key>": "<value>"}`

---

**Code:**

```
$('#sumbit_configPost').on 'click', ->
username = $('#login_username').val()
password = $('#login_password').val()
mac_id = $('#login_ConfigPostmac').val()
key_id = $('#login_ConfigPostkey').val()
console.dir key_id
console.dir data
$.ajax
  type: "POST"
  url: start_url + mac_id + "/config/"
  dataType: "json"
  data: {key_id}
  crossDomain: true
  cache: false
  beforeSend: beforeSend

  success: (data) ->
  ... Code Continues
```

Thank You In Address

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a valid key/value pair:

```
data: {key_id}
```

Maybe you mean something like this?:

```
data: {"key":key_id}
```

The `key_id` value itself needs some kind of key within the data so it can be referenced.  That key here is just the string "key" but could be anything you need, depending on how you're expecting to reference it in the server-side code.  In this case it would be something like:

```
$_POST['key']
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it like this:

```
$('#sumbit_configPost').on 'click', function(){
      username = $('#login_username').val();
      password = $('#login_password').val();
      mac_id = $('#login_ConfigPostmac').val();
      key_id = $('#login_ConfigPostkey').val();
     // console.dir key_id;
     // console.dir data;
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: start_url + mac_id + "/config/",
         dataType: "json",
         data: {key_id:key_id}, //<===== Sending values
         crossDomain: true,
         cache: false,
         beforeSend: beforeSend,

         success: function(data){
           ... Code Continues
         }
     }); 
  });
```

Now you will be able to accept `key_id` as `$_POST['key_id']` variable.